# Is there a way to trigger a network buffer flush in Python?

Tags: python, network-programming

Specifically on an Apple, with Python 3.9.10, I am using the socket `sendall` method to send a data buffer on a network connection that has successfully opened to a server. The data that I am sending does not reach the server until I use the socket's `close` method when I give up on waiting for data to be returned.

The intent is for the Python script to act as a network client to contact a server and do some minimal data transactions. The server is running as a service on a Linux machine. The client-side script spawns a thread to do the network communication with

```
import threading, sys

t = threading.Thread(target=social_init, daemon=True)
t.start()
```

The code in question (in part) is:

```
import socket               # Import socket module and JSON parser module
import json
def social_init():
    global social1_resps, social2_resps, social3_resps
    host = "test.mydomain.com"  # Get server name
    port = 6942                 # this is where the server is listening
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.settimeout(30.0)    # note: 30 second timeout
        s.connect((host, port))
        sbuf = json.dumps({"rmv":"1","gameID":9,"function":1})
        bbuf = sbuf.encode('utf-8')
        nbytes = len(bbuf)
        s.sendall(nbytes.to_bytes(4, 'little'))
        s.sendall(bbuf)

        nnbuf = s.recv(4)
        nbytes = int.from_bytes(nnbuf, 'little')
        bbuf = s.recv(nbytes)
        sbuf = str(bbuf, 'utf-8')
        obj = json.loads(sbuf)
        while (obj != None):
            # actual processing of returned data elided

        s.close()                   # Close the socket when done
```

This code works as expected on Windows and Linux hosts, but on an Apple host the server sees the connection happen, but no data. When the client times out the receive, or when the script terminates (which forces the connection closed), we see the data being sent - I've checked timing by running Wireshark on the server.

I'm aware of the existence of the `flush()` function, but because we're using sockets rather than the file handle abstraction, `flush` apparently does not apply. Is there an equivalent method that can be used on a socket to force flushing of the network buffer?

Comment: Don't assume `recv(n)` receives exactly *n* bytes.  It can be 1-n bytes or zero for a socket close.  You can wrap the socket in a file-like object via [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) and use `.read(n)`, which will buffer and return *n* bytes unless error or EOF (socket close) similar to a file.  `.flush()` can also be used on a writable makefile wrapper (and needs to be, since it is buffered).  Your problem could also be on the server side, since that code isn't shown.

Comment: Note `sbuf = str(bbuf, 'utf-8')` is unneeded.  `json.loads` assumes UTF-8 encoding if passed a `bytes` object.  `s.close()` also is unneeded since a `with` is used.

Comment: @MarkTolonen the original code used `socket.makefile` and exhibited the same behavior, and had some other behavior that was less than optimal. Reverting to the `sendall` socket code was done in an attempt to remove some abstractions that might be causing the problem. As mentioned, the code works properly with Windows and Linux clients, it's only Apples that seem to show the problem, and I don't think Wireshark would lie about when packets appeared, so I don't suspect the server.

Comment: I'm just pointing out potential problems.  That's why it is a comment not an answer.  Check the length of `.recv()` to make sure you are receiving what you think; otherwise, I don't see a problem.